# How to keep long text elements in the same line via css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, tag-cloud

I am not a css/html expert so I'm sorry if I can not explain the problem properly.

I have 2 Wordpress sites with different themes, and I used same widget for them to show the tags. In 1st site, let's name it **A**, the tags go after another in the same line, even if a tag must be break. In the 2nd site, **B**, tags go after another too, but in case of all words of a tag can't be at the same line, this tag would go to next line.

**UPDATE:** What I got in **B** is like this:

> first tag
>
> very large second tag

But in **A** I got this:

> first tag very large
>
> second tag

These tags are different elements, each of which consists of a and span.

This makes white gaps in tag cloud which I don't like. I tried to inspect two themes css via firefox and compare them to identify what to do, but couldn't find the reason. I made any difference in **A** in **B** via firefox inspect element but it didn't work.

I put all css codes which firefox gives for the element div#tag-groups-cloud-tabs... in both sites below:

for site **A**:

```
inline 139:
*::-moz-selection {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(73, 138, 184);
}

style.css 137:
*::-moz-selection {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(73, 138, 184);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

inline:
element {
}

style.css 40:
*, html, body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, label, fieldset, input, p, blockquote, th, td {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    outline: 0px none;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
}

style.css 104:
* {
    outline: medium none;
}

style.css 197:
body {
    font: 13px/20px tahoma,'PT Sans',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    color: rgb(67, 67, 67);
}
```

and for site **B**:

```
style.css 470:
*::-moz-selection {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(36, 137, 13);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-shadow: none;
}

style.css 758:
.footer-sidebar:after, .hentry:after, .slider-direction-nav:after, .contributor-info:after, .search-box:after, [class*="content"]:after, [class*="site"]:after {
    clear: both;
}

style.css 740:
.footer-sidebar:before, .footer-sidebar:after, .hentry:before, .hentry:after, .slider-direction-nav:before, .slider-direction-nav:after, .contributor-info:before, .contributor-info:after, .search-box:before, .search-box:after, [class*="content"]:before, [class*="content"]:after, [class*="site"]:before, [class*="site"]:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

inline:
element {
}

rtl.css 34:
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    border: 0px none;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: 0px none;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

style.css 64:
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    border: 0px none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: 0px none;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

style.css 2073:
.widget {
    font-size: 14px;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    line-height: 1.28571;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

style.css 2055:
.content-sidebar {
    color: rgb(118, 118, 118);
}

rtl.css 121:
body, button, input, select, textarea {
    color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

rtl.css 101:
body {
    direction: rtl;
}

style.css 102:
body, button, input, select, textarea {
    color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
    font-family: Lato,sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

for one line statement use `white-space:nowrap;`

[**see demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jZpw5/1/)

Comment: The problem is not what you demonstrated. I will add it to the question itself.

Comment: apologies....could u just provide a fiddle as your HMTL markup is not there...m sure prob is related to `white-space`...would be able to help better then!! :)

Comment: in B you use word-wrap: break-word; //normal - A don't have that. You can set this if you will have very long text in one line or if you want move text to next line when text is too long.

Comment: i'll need HTML markup to help....what is the markup for the tags?? `<span>`,`<div>` etc???